# iteration, batch size and iteration in code

Tags: machine-learning

I have this code of Network neural

```
var sy = require("synaptic");

// create the network
var inputLayer = new sy.Layer(28*28);
var hiddenLayer = new sy.Layer(10);
var outputLayer = new sy.Layer(1);

inputLayer.project(hiddenLayer);
hiddenLayer.project(outputLayer);

var myNetwork = new sy.Network({
    input: inputLayer,
    hidden: [hiddenLayer],
    output: outputLayer
});

// train the network
var learningRate = .3;
for (var i = 0; i < 20; i++)
{
    console.log(i);

    for(var j = 0; j< MyData.length; j++){
        myNetwork.activate(training_set_inputs[j]);
        myNetwork.propagate(learningRate, [training_set_inputs[0][j]]);
    }
}
```

my question is what is epoch, batch and iteration in the code, 
Taking into account that:We can divide the dataset of 2000 examples into batches of 500 then it will take 4 iterations to complete 1 epoch.

Answer (score 1):

An epoch is one pass over the dataset. An iteration is a pass over your batch. A batch is some number of training samples you have. So, it seems you have 20 epochs, data length iterations with batch size = 1, i.e. stochastic GD.

Comment: for(var j = 0; j< MyData.length; j++){ is the batch?

Comment: it seems you call propagate at each single training sample, i.e. batch size is 1. So, that's not the batch. It is the iteration loop.

Comment: @hubman is the answer ok for you?